# Firebase dynamic link creating gives error "There was an error creating a dynamic link"

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've set up Firebase Dynamic links on my website. I'm using the `/links` to not interfere with the other pages on the site. Most of the steps it's pretty much default setup but it still gives an error at the last step.

Step 1: define the link
[image]

Step 2: My first dynamic link will be `openaccount`
[image]

Step 3, 4 are default. It redirects to the Play / App Store when not installed.
[image]

Last step: it shows that an unknown error has occured?
[image]

Check the hosting tab, everything is connected:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Whitelist URL pattern doesn't allow it. You can check your Whitelist URL pattern settings in Firebase console by clicking the 3 dots next to New Dynamic Link button. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets stuck on this what helped me was adding a '/' at the end of the Deep Link URL.

So In the OPs example instead of

https://example.example.app/links/openaccount

it should be

https://example.example.app/links/openaccount/

Go figure... :)